# ADAL.JS to pick logged in user directly instead of showing account selection screen

Tags: javascript, adal.js

Am expecting ADAL.js code to automatically pick the user and login into my web application instead of throwing user to account selection screen, where he just click on account and he gets in with out even entering password. but am looking to avoid account selection screen. it all should happen behind the scene.

```
function invokeGraphApi() {


    // #4: Get an access token to the Microsoft Graph API
    authContext.acquireToken(azurePorperties.endpoints.graphApiUri,
        function (error, token) {
            // TODO: Handle error obtaining access token
            if (error || !token) {
                displayAlert('danger', "User details not found, Kindly relogin");              
                return;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: azurePorperties.endpoints.graphApiUri + "/v1.0/me",
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    //disableWaitingPointer();
                }, error: function (result) {

                    console.log("Error at GraphApi/V1.0/Me:" + result);
                    displayAlert('danger', 'Error occured at Graphapi/v1.0/me ');

                }

            });

        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The application has access to the user's authentication context and wants to avoid the Azure AD account selection prompt when multiple accounts are signed in. This can be done a few different ways:

- Session Id or SID

  You can pass the SID in the request parameters to the **`acquireTokenSilent`** call. This will allow Azure AD to bypass the account selection. SID , you can configure SID in optional claim
- Login hint

  If you do not have SID claim configured or need to bypass the account selection prompt in interactive authentication calls, you can do so by providing a login_hint in the request parameters

You can follow below doc for further reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso#automatically-select-account-on-azure-ad

Also , you can find the detailed samples in below repo:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki#sso-between-apps

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, am using adal.js where as above solution is suggesting to use msal.js. hence would like to understand, will it be major change migrating to msal.js ? and by any chance do you know how to achieve same using adal.js